# How to make porn websites return a 404 error?

Tags: windows, windows-7, dns, website-blocker

I'm looking for an effective porn blocking software or DNS that does not show a custom error page when going on a blocked website.

I want it to act like the blocked website does not exist without redirecting (changing URL), thus returning a 404 error on the original URL.

Is there any solution out, already? I prefer free things, but I would be interested for a solution that costs money, too.

Comment: That's rather asking for a howto ([How to Block All Adult Websites using Free OpenDNS](http://www.kidzsearch.com/blog/how-to-block-adult-websites-using-free-opendns/)) rather than for software – especially as you don't even mention the basics like what OS it should run on or what your price limit is ;)

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, I edited my question to provide this information. Well, I'm aware how to setup a custom DNS on my router. My problem is such DNS services will always redirect to a different page telling the user the website got blocked. I don't want that. It would be great the user would not even recognize this website exists.

Comment: Hm. Then you could maybe use [Unbound DNS](https://unbound.net/download.html) with an "adult block list" (see [DNS server for blacklisting tons of domains and also some TLDs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268356/209279) and watch out for "Securemecca")? Alternatively, as pointed out, use OpenDNS [and their adult filter](https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/?url=familyshield) – other than you expect, they AFAIK don't lead you to a landing page but deliver the correct "not found". At least they do without filters (using that myself, but didn't try their filters).

Answer (score 1):

**There's is no absolute solution**. There are *millions* of adult websites on the internet and thousands of new ones are created every day, no one can have a complete list of all URLs.

For blocking websites you can use a web proxy such as [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) or block at router level, for example.

Comment: Systems admin best practices is to block *everything* and then allow what you want unless there is a known, discrete list of things to block.